# Java - Assign button arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays, button

Is it possible for me to assign already created buttons into an array?

For simplicity, I have this. But I'm going to have up to 50 buttons, and this works, but it's repetitive. Can I just assign them into an array already instead of doing it one by one?

```
Button [] BtnArray = new Button[3];            
BtnArray[0] = btn1;
BtnArray[1] = btn2;
BtnArray[2] = btn3;
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work

```
BtnArray = {btn1, btn2, btn3};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need 50 buttons? use `Recycler` view

Comment: It's 2017. Use [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: Did you just ask this same question a few hours ago?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen haha, no. My first question was for onClick buttons. This one is just asking if I can put them into an array so I can add text to each button easier

Comment: Yes you can add them to an array, or better yet a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even its a very bad approach to make 50 buttons (can't even think of a way to use 50 buttons in 1 window), this is what you kinda tried:

```
Button btn1 = new Button();
Button btn2 = new Button();
Button btn3 = new Button();
Button[] BtnArray = new Button[] { btn1, btn2, btn3 };
```

you will then be able to access the 3 buttons with `BtnArray[i]` where `i` is a number between 0 and 2 both included.

If you have more question, just ask. A tip which was already given in comments is to use a collection and generate the buttons dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you have a series of elements and want them to be stored in a collection, You have to add them to that collection. The data structure you are using depends on the system/app requirement. Sometimes the length of data is not clear, you can use data structures with dynamic lengths. Or sometimes you need to store data in term of **key** and **value**, you can you **Map**. Anyway, you can easily use `ArrayList` in bellow way.

```
        Button btn1 = new Button();
        Button btn2 = new Button();
        //...
        ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
        buttons.add(btn1);
        buttons.add(btn2);
        //...
```

Answer (score -5):

If you want to add exactly 50 Buttons to array you can create array of length 50 and in loop create Buttons and put them at corresponding index in array;

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[50];
for(int i=0;i < buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i] = new Button();
}
```

Comment: Why do you link this website to all your answers? StackOverflow is not 
an advertising platform.

Comment: I removed that link. I think people can get help there

Comment: For info, you're being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352023/user-keeps-adding-link-to-some-java-expert-chat-page-in-every-answer)